# When I try to happen to the second URL I created it says "Page not found" and "calls it" 3. ^ (? P <path>. *) $

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

It does not show me the url created. When I try to go to the localhost it tells me: admin /
Borsa/
^ (? P . *) $

The created URL calls it ^ (? P . *) $. How can I do?

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.Borsa),
    path('Investimenti', views.Investimenti)

]
```

urls.py (project)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('Borsa/', include('Borsa.urls')),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root =settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Aziende
def Borsa(request):
    Borsa = Aziende.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Borsa/Home.html', {'Borsa': Borsa},)

def Investimenti(request):
    return render(request, 'Borsa/Investimenti.html')
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you are running the correct Django project? There is no such url pattern as `Bag/` (From what you say is shown in the error) in the patterns that you show.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's the translation.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you trying to visit `admin/Borsa/`  and receiving `Page not found` error

Comment: No, when I try to go to 127.0.0.1/Investimenti it tells me Page not found. When I try to go to see the existing urls it tells me that (Investimenti) is called ^ (? P <path>. *) $.

Comment: Can you please share the exact output you receive? Please set `LANGUAGES = [('en_US', 'English')]` and `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en_US'` temporarily in your settings before sharing the output, so you don't have to translate it manually.

Comment: @Beabel `127.0.0.1/Investimenti`? No you won't have that url since it is included from `Borsa/`, instead you have `127.0.0.1/Borsa/Investimenti` also note ending your url patterns in a trailing slash `/` is important hence change `path('Investimenti', views.Investimenti)` to `path('Investimenti/', views.Investimenti)`